# $(LOCAL_PATH) not returning the path to current directory correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I am using Android NDK to compile a shared library. I am using the latest build of Android Studio (Android Studio 15- #AI-141.2422023 ). In my cpp code, I am using a thirdparty shared library. When writing the Android.mk file, I have first created a PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY with the following code.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := essentia
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../essentia-shared/lib/libessentia.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../essentia-shared/include/essentia

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The problem I am facing is that `$(LOCAL_PATH)` is behaving a bit weirdly. The path it is returning is

```
 jni/jni/../../../essentia-shared/lib/libessentia.so
```

I have the following questions:

1. I am not sure, why there are two `jni's` appended at the front of the path. Also when I tried to print the value of `LOCAL_PATH` by using `$(warning $(LOCAL_PATH))`, it prints `jni`.
2. Shouldn't `$(LOCAL_PATH)` return the absolute path? This is even more confusing because at times I got the absolute path using `$(LOCAL_PATH)`.

PS: I am using the terminal internal to Android Studio to run `ndk-build`

**Edit 1:** I run the `ndk-build` from `src/main`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(call my-dir)` from `src/main` for **src/main/jni/Android.mk** results in `"jni"`. On the other hand, `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` are always treated relative to the `LOCAL_PATH`, which is `"jni"`. That's how `jni/jni` appears for your **.so**.

On the other hand, all `…_INCLUDES` are treated relative to working directory, which in your case is `src/main` from where you launched **ndk-build**. Due to the delicate nature of current directory, it is a good practice to use absolute paths for all include paths.

So, this is the suggested rewrite of this part of your **Android.mk**:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := app-lib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := a.cpp b.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := essentia
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_PATH += /../../../essentia-shared
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := essentia
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/libessentia.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(abspath $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/essentia)
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. For my particular case, I am also building a final `BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY` using this `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY`. So, I kept the `LOCAL_PATH` as ` $(call my-dir)` and used the relative path in case of `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` and the absolute path in case of `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` and it seems to work fine. Thanks again!

Comment: But, I am still curious as to why `$(warning $(LOCAL_PATH))` sometimes return absolute path and sometimes return relative path (`jni`). Any explanation for this?

Comment: Fine. You can redefine `LOCAL_PATH` in your **Android.mk** as you wish. See the update.

Comment: You are free to set `LOCAL_PATH` to absolute or relative; NDK will understand either.